# Memory usage increasing ~10kb every frame

Tags: java, android, memory-efficiency, memory

I am currently developing a game for Android (using the SDK) and have been trying to reduce the memory usage. I have discovered that during each frame, the memory usage increases by about 10kb. The game runs at 60fps so adds over half a megabyte every second which, over time, significantly increases the total memory usage of the game.

This is not a huge problem as, after a short while, the memory is released by the garbage collector and it returns to a normal level. Despite this, I would like to know if such per-frame memory increases are normal for games developed in Java. If not, are there any tips or solutions to reducing the framely memory increase (other than not instantiating objects in every update/draw call - I have made sure I'm not doing this).

This is the draw method for my game:

```
public void draw(Canvas canvas){
    if(screenScaleX > 1f || screenScaleY > 1f)
        canvas.scale(screenScaleX, screenScaleY);

    canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
    if(skipFrames > 0){
        skipFrames--;
        return;
    }

    pp.preDraw(this, canvas);

    scrollX = (player == null ? 0 : player.getBounds().getX()) * SCALE_FACTOR - 1280f / 2f;
    scrollY = (player == null ? 0 : player.getBounds().getY()) * SCALE_FACTOR - 720f / 2f;

    if(battle != null)
        battle.draw(this, canvas);

    popTranslate(canvas);

    canvas.scale(SCALE_FACTOR, SCALE_FACTOR);

    synchronized(objects){
        if(objectModCount > 0){
            Collections.sort(objects, GameObject.RenderLayer.RENDER_COMPARATOR);
            objectModCount = 0;
        }

        uCopy.clear();
        uCopy.addAll(objects);
        for(GameObject obj : uCopy){
            if(battle != null)
                if(!(obj instanceof Dialog))
                    continue;
            if(!obj.shouldScale())
                canvas.scale(SCALE_FACTOR_1, SCALE_FACTOR_1);

            obj.draw(this, canvas);

            if(!obj.shouldScale())
                canvas.scale(SCALE_FACTOR, SCALE_FACTOR);
        }
    }

    pp.draw(this, canvas);

    canvas.scale(SCALE_FACTOR_1, SCALE_FACTOR_1);

    pushTranslate(canvas);

    windows.draw(this, canvas);
    guis.draw(canvas, this);
    pp.postDraw(this, canvas);

    if(FRAME_SYNC){
        if(delta > 17L && delta < 33L){
            dSyncDiff = 33 - delta;
            try{
                Thread.sleep(dSyncDiff);
            }catch(InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    frameCounter++;

    if(screenScaleX > 1f || screenScaleY > 1f)
        canvas.scale(1f / screenScaleX, 1f / screenScaleY);
}
```

As can be seen in the code above, I do not instantiate any objects, even primitives so the memory should not increase. All of my rendering and update code follows this sort of style so should be the same. Unless Androids SDK is memory inefficient (which I don't imagine it is), I really cannot see why or how the memory increase so much every frame. I have moved all primitives that are used to members of the class that owns this draw method and done the same for all others.

Update: Could it possibly be due to unavoidable creation of strings. For example, because strings are immutable, I would have to create a new string every time I want to update the contents of some text being drawn to the screen (and this does happen framely).

Comment: You may be able to get some "tips or solutions" to avoiding memory growth overall at a discussion forum like [GDNet](http://www.gamedev.net). Without a minimal example of the problem you're talking about, though, we can't really diagnose it here.

Comment: @JoshPetrie thanks for the reply - I am more interested to see whether this is normal than get a solution. I will post a few examples of my rendering and update methods. Judging by your response, I am guessing it is not normal for games to increase their memory usage at this rate?

Comment: It does seem suspect to me; even if it ends up being "typical" Java behavior, you're potentially allowing for hitches during that GC phase so if you can preallocate to avoid the growth and thus the GC that would likely be better.

Comment: @JoshPetrie Thank you again for the response. I'm pretty certain I preallocate everything I use (I'm still trying to pick the most relevant example from my code to post as an example).

Comment: I'd start by focusing on the section including uCopy. The .clear() releases memory, and the .addAll() allocates memory.  Does uCopy produce any functionality that isn't available in objects?

Comment: @MikeWhite uCopy avoids concurrency issues when looping through it.